# Create new JSON with sum of values in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have below array,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack1 [amount] => 100.00 [category_name] => Trial1 ) [1] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack1 [amount] => 150.00 [category_name] => Trial2 ) [2] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack1 [amount] => 200.00 [category_name] => Trial1 ) [3] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack2 [amount] => 200.00 [category_name] => Trial2 ) [4] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack2 [amount] => 200.00 [category_name] => Trial1 ) [5] => Array ( [user_name] => Jack2 [amount] => 200.00 [category_name] => Trial2 )
```

What i want to send to have JSON with below format

It will get some of Equal category name and then send it as json.

```
[{'user_name': Jack1, 'trial1':"300", 'trial2':150"" }, {'user_name': Jack2, 'trial1':"200", 'trial2':400"" }]
```

In summary, i want to username as unique and then put all category with name and sum of each category for that user,

Tried below,

```
$new_array = array();

        foreach ($expense_array['x'] as $a)
        {
            if (!isset($new_array[$a['user_name']]['amount']))
            {
                $new_array[$a['user_name']]['amount'] = 0;
            }

            $new_array[$a['user_name']] = array(
                    'user_name' => $a['user_name'],
                    'category_name' => $a['category_name'],
                    'amount' => $new_array[$a['user_name']]['amount'] + $a['amount']);

        }
echo json_encode(array_values($new_array));
```

This only output trai1 category, not as required JSON

How can i achieve this?
Was thinking to get `foreach` loop and then make compare of category_name and use .=+ to get sum? but i lost there,

Thanks,

Comment: please format this . and put some valid json data

Comment: Are you getting this data from the database?

Comment: @peterm, yes i am getting array output from DB, and want to create PHP loop to output JSON

Comment: Then it's better / more natural do grouping on the db side.

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts too. SO is not free code writing service

Comment: why don't you update your SQL query to get the sum of trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the array into this function it will return the json string that you want:

```
function create_json($data)
{
    $output = [];

    foreach ( $data as $stats )
    {
        $key      = $stats['user_name'];
        $category = strtolower($stats['category_name']);
        $amount = $stats['amount'];

        if ( isset($output[$key]) )
        {
            if ( isset($output[$key][$category]) )
            {
                $output[$key][$category] += $amount;
            }
            else
            {
                $output[$key][$category] = $amount;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $output[$key] = [
                'user_name' => $key,
                $category   => $amount,
            ];
        }
    }

    return json_encode(array_values($output));
}
```

Output:

```
[
{"user_name":"Jack1","trial1":300,"trial2":150},
{"user_name":"Jack2","trial2":400,"trial1":200}
]
```

Comment: Sane, almost there, but how can i get sum of all category amount for Jack1 , 2?

Comment: @rjcode, So you want it to output the sum of each category and the total sum of all categories? if so then change you example JSON to reflect that and I'll make it match.

Comment: @rjcode, if you look at the example output from my post you will see that it matches you example, so I'm still confused on what is missing?

The category's totals are small because I used the dataset array you provided

Comment: i don't want total categories, but amount total where each Trial 1 and 2 for Jack1 and 2

Comment: @rjcode, I understand now, I've changed the function to reflect what I think you want.